# From y(x) animation to y(t) at a given x

Tags: python, matplotlib, args, keyword-argument

I am currently running code simulating a string's motion, and I wish to read its amplitude at a given point and plot this as a function of time, thus representing data that would be read from a guitar's pickup.  As I am new to animation in python, the task of obtaining data while presenting this animation has proved a challenge.  Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import exp
#import matplotlib.animation as animation

#Power Spectrum
def PowerSpectrum(f):
    return (f*f.conjugate()).real/len(f)**2

#triangular pulse
def triangular_pulse(x, xmean, sigma):
    return np.where(x<xmean,x*sigma/xmean,sigma-(x-xmean)*(sigma/(200-xmean)))

N_masses = 200
T  = 0.0669264714
mu = .03937
cSq = T/mu
c  = np.sqrt(cSq)
dx = 1.0

dt = dx/c
print dt

#Initialize some arrays
x0  = np.arange(N_masses)*dx
y   = np.zeros(N_masses)
vy  = np.zeros(N_masses)
ay  = np.zeros(N_masses)

#setup for animation
fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.ion()
wave, = plt.plot(x0,y)
plt.ylim(-30,30)

#Set Initial conditions (pluck)
# # half-pluck
# y = 30*gaussian_pulse(x0,x0[N_masses/2],2)

# quarter-pluck
y = triangular_pulse(x0,x0[N_masses/10],6)

yprev = y - vy*dt
y1 = []


t=0.0
i=0
while t<1000:
    dydx = (y[1:] - y[:-1])/dx
    ay[1:-1] = ( dydx[1:] - dydx[:-1] )/dx * cSq
    # Notice we update both at the same time
    yprev, y = y, exp(-.00001*t)*(2*y - yprev + ay * dt**2)
    t = t + dt
    y1.append(y[1])
    i += 1

    if i%1==0:
        wave.set_data(x0,y)
        plt.draw()

gauss_hat = np.fft.fft(y1)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y1), d=1.0/100)
half_ps = PowerSpectrum(gauss_hat)

#half-pluck y[1] vs. t
plt.plot(range(1000), y1)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y[1]')
plt.title('y[1] vs. t')

# power spectrum plots
#plt.plot(freqs,half_ps)
#plt.xlabel('frequency (Hz)')
#plt.ylabel('Intensity')

#plt.title('y[1] Power Spectrum (half pluck)')
#plt.title('y[1] Power Spectrum (quarter pluck)')

#plt.grid(True)
#plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

The animation runs, but no plot is presented.  I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/defaultuser/Downloads/compare.py", line 69, in <module>
    plt.plot(range(1000), y1)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2467, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 3893, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 322, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 300, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 240, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
[Finished in 30.6s with exit code 1]
```

## Update

That error no longer appears, as the code has been modified to `plt.plot(y1)` thus granting x and y the same dimension.  After commenting out plotting code responsible for the animation, a good graph was obtained.  Thus I learned the plt.plot function can't be called more than once and that subplot is required instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and last lines in the traceback:

```
  File "/Users/defaultuser/Downloads/compare.py", line 69, in <module>
    plt.plot(range(1000), y1)
...
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
```

suggest that  `range(1000)` and `y1` do not have the same shape.
Indeed, if you paste the code in an interactive session, you'll find

```
In [17]: len(y1)
Out[17]: 1304
```

which makes sense since the loop increments `t` by an amount `dt` and `dt < 1`:

```
t = 0.0
while t<1000:
    t = t + dt
    y1.append(...)

In [18]: dt
Out[18]: 0.76697947735477701
```

---

You can fix the problem by simply using the 1-argument form of `plt.plot`:

```
plt.plot(y1)
```

which is equivalent to

```
plt.plot(range(len(y1)), y1)
```

Comment: Ah, much thanks.  I am no longer receiving that error, however no graph is displayed following the animation. Is this because plt.plot is already used in setting up the animation?  Should and can I use subplots for each, instead?